# Kendo UI for Angular Exporting selected rows to Excel

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using Kendo UI for Angular and I am trying to export my grid to Excel. I have implemented a solution like this: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/

and it does work. It exports all rows in my grid. My problem is that I only want to export **selected** rows. I haven't been able to successfully filter the allData method to only export selected rows.

It looks to me like the process method called from within the allData method can take a State object that has a filter: component. But for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work. Can anybody point me to a simple example where the selected rows only are exported to Excel?

Thanks,
John B.

Comment: Please put some code on what you have done. i worked on the similar functionality couple of days back and i can be able to help you if i see your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented selected rows and selection key to be entire row so that when I export i can retrieve the selected rows and modified export allData to export selection data if exists.If selection doesnot exists then exports all data.

```
     public mySelectionKey(context: RowArgs): string {

           // return context.dataItem.serialNumber + " " + context.index;
           return context.dataItem;
       }

     public allData(): ExcelExportData {
         let selInventory: Inventory[] = [];
         let result: ExcelExportData;

          selInventory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mySelection));



       if (selInventory.length > 0) {
             result = {
              data: process(selInventory, {
              sort: [{ field: "serialNumber", dir: "asc" }]
             }).data
            };
        } else {
             result = {
               data: process(this.inventoryData, {
              sort: [{ field: "serialNumber", dir: "asc" }]
               }).data
            };
          }

           return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Export selected or all rows

```
 function excelExport() {
    var exportAll = $('.selectrow').is(":checked");
    var grid = $("#grid");
    var rows = [{
        cells: [
            { value: "column1" },
            { value: "column2" },
            { value: "column3" },
            { value: "column4" },
            { value: "column5" },
            { value: "column6" },
            { value: "column7" }
        ]
    }];
    if (exportAll) {
        var dataDource = grid.getKendoGrid();
        var trs = $("#grid").find('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
            if ($(trs[i]).find(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
                var dataItem = dataDource.dataItem(trs[i]);
                rows.push({
                    cells: [
                        { value: dataItem.column1 },
                        { value: dataItem.column2 },
                        { value: dataItem.column3 },
                        { value: dataItem.column4 },
                        { value: dataItem.column5 },
                        { value: dataItem.column6 },
                        { value: dataItem.column7 }
                    ]
                })
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        var dataSource = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var trs = grid.find('tr');
        for (var i = 1; i < dataSource._data.length; i++) {
                var dataItem = dataSource._data[i];
                rows.push({
                    cells: [
                        { value: dataItem.column1 },
                        { value: dataItem.column2 },
                        { value: dataItem.column3 },
                        { value: dataItem.column4 },
                        { value: dataItem.column5 },
                        { value: dataItem.column6 },
                        { value: dataItem.column7 }
                    ]
                })
        }
    }



    var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
        sheets: [
            {
                columns: [
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true },
                    { autoWidth: true }
                ],
                title: "Exported Result",
                rows: rows
            }
        ]
    });
    kendo.saveAs({ dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(), fileName: "ExportedResult" });
}
```